# List Binding with model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

So I have a form that I am trying to submit and I can get either the list or the model to bind, but not both at the same time.  I suspect it has to do with the model binder.

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="TransferHeader">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tranRequestedBy)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tranRequestedBy, new { @Name = "h.tranRequestedBy" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tranNotes)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tranNotes, new { @Name = "h.tranNotes" })
        </div>
       <input name="h.TransfersDetail.Index" id="detIndex" type="hidden" value="c3a3f7dd-41bb-4b95-b2a6-ab5125868adb">
       <input name="h.TransfersDetail[c3a3f7dd-41bb-4b95-b2a6-ab5125868adb].detToolCode" id="detToolCode" type="hidden" value="1234">
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(TransfersHeader h)
{
    return View();
}
```

Model Class:

```
public virtual ICollection<TransfersDetail> TransfersDetail { get; set; }
public string tranRequestedBy { get; set; }
public string tranNotes { get; set; }
```

The two bottom inputs were generated from an AJAX call to an add method, what happens is if they are not present the two HTML helper editors will come in the model, but if they do exist only the transfer detail list will appear.
Is there anything I could do to make sure all of the data comes into the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear how you are generating those inputs, but the `name` attributes are incorrect. You model does not contain a collection property named `h`, but it does contain one named `TransfersDetail`, so your inputs need to be

```
<input name="TransfersDetail.Index" type="hidden" value="c3a3f7dd-41bb-4b95-b2a6-ab5125868adb">
<input name="TransfersDetail[c3a3f7dd-41bb-4b95-b2a6-ab5125868adb].detToolCode" type="hidden" value="1234">
```

Its also not clear why your adding an `id` attribute (if you referencing collection items in jQuery, you would be better off using class names and relative selectors), but the `id` your using does not have an indexer suggesting that your going to be generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html (and jQuery selectors would not work in any case)

Comment: thanks, that worked, I was naming the list item after the controller's expectation of h.